# How to programmatically smoothly zoom to a point with panzoom?

Tags: javascript, panzoom

Using the [panzoom](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom) library, assuming the containing div is 400x300px, and an interesting item is found on 120-150x200-250 (Before zooming), how can one programmatically zoom to this rectangle with a smooth zoom in?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried `smoothZoom()`, `smoothZoomAbs()`, `zoomTo()`, `moveTo()`, `centerOn()`, and even manually with `getTransform()`. The lib is very simple to set up - but the API docs are missing.

Comment: Which panzoom? There's a bunch of them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: question updated with lib link.

Comment: May you share an [mcve] of your `zoomTo`/`moveTo` attempt? I can't see how else you can do it, unless you use `kinetic.js` directly?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: no. This is a basic question.  Compare with leaflet's [`panTo()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-panto) or [`fitBounds()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-fitbounds) methods.

Comment: `pz.showRectangle` looks promising, but it doesn't look like the library has an equivalent to `fitBounds()`.